# If we create a derived object, is the parent object also automatically created?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

If I create derived object it calls base constructor first and then derived constructor. Does it mean that parent object also get created when we create derive object?

I don't think parent object gets created, but why does the parent constructor get called?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 class A {
      public :  A(){ 
                  cout<<"inside A constructor"<<endl;
       }
    };
   class B : public A{
                  public : B(){
                            cout << "inside B constructor" << endl;
                          }
        };
    int main() {
                B b; 
               return 0;
            }
```

Output:

```
inside A constructor
inside B constructor
```

Comment: "I don't think parent object get created " why do you think so?

Comment: B **is-a** A... so, it's right there in this relationship.

Comment: If you think of classes as categories (or a *classification*) of objects, you soon realize that you can't create a dog or a cat without creating an animal; you can't create a student or a plumber without creating a person...

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think parent object get created [...]

You are wrong.

`B` constists of a `A` subobject and any members that `B` has in addition. Consider this example:

```
struct A {
    int a = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    B() {}
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.a = 42;
}
```

`B` inherits the members from `A`. Those members do not come out of nowhere, but they are part of `B`s subobject of type `A` and that has to be constructed. When you do not call a constructor explicitly then it will be default constructed. The above is roughly equivalent to:

```
struct A {
    int a = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    B() : A() {}
       // ^^^ call default constructor of A
};
```